# How to deal with the high current flowing into your wires?

Tags: current, switches, dc-motor

So i've got this 1000 watt 36V with a full-load current of 35,6 amps. In the circuit I want to wire a switch that can handle this high current. Unfortunately it seems that I cant find a switch (specific reason?). What can I do to deal with the high current. I am making an electric gokart btw.

Ps: In a circuit, does the motor pulls 35,6 amps into my wires or is it the battery?

Comment: You need to take a step back and seriously consider what you're doing.  36A is a lot and you clearly have no idea what is going on.  But probably a power MOSFET is what you're looking for, or a relay?

Comment: An automotive starter solenoid might work. Not sure if it can handle 36V, but 35 amps is nothing for it. Also, they make equipment for these kinds of things if you look in electric vehicle websites. Finally, there are also battery switches for boats and RV's. Google "Guest battery switch." People often use the phrase "pulls 35.6 Amps". What they mean is that when the switch is on, there will be 35.6 Amps going to the motor. Do not be so concerned whether the motor "pulls" or the battery "pushes." The point is that they both have to be connected for the current to flow.

Comment: DC switches are subjected to more stress than AC switches. Every time you turn off a switch, there is probably at least a tiny little electric arc. With higher currents, and with inductive loads, this is more true and more noticeable. With AC switches, the arc may form, but it is extinguished at the moment the voltage or current crosses zero. But with DC current, the arc may persist for a long time, or even indefinitely, because the ionized air between the contacts is conductive. https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=dUawgIHlLhs

Answer (score 1):

As said already you need to take a step back and start learning basic DC electronics and some automotive electrical.

Typically in a car for example you are switching remotely a relay or solenoid on and off. This means large wires don't have to detour through the cab (shorter runs so less voltage drop) and you can use smaller more intricate switches among other benefits.

Think of your headlight switch on your dash or indicator stalk, this then triggers a relay under the bonnet. So the loom to power your headlights just has to travel from battery to fuse box and relay then on to your headlights.

Another problem will be protection of wiring. Not sure if they use the chassis of a go kart like in a car and bond it to the negative terminal but if they do there is potential for shorting on the frame or each other due to wires chafing, rubbing, melting and so on. So you will need to know how to select the right gauge of wiring and protection for the wiring, typically a fuse and where to locate it.

Lastly, how is the motor actually driving the go kart?

I am no expert on motors by any means but is it direct drive by a chain or belt ?

How are you going to do 'throttle' and control the rpm of the motor ?

Unless you are purely asking about a manual on/off switch ?

Any gearing, transfer case or clutch of some sort ?

Are you going to want to do regenerative braking, have the motor brake dynamically or just free wheel?

Motor driving one way or capable of reverse ?

How are you going to monitor charge and battery status ?

Sounds like a microcontroller or similar could be handy ?

Even if you only want this at the back I would imagine you may need a kill switch accessible to the driver up front?

You need to flesh this out more.

Answer (score 1):

The magic word for high-current switching is a "contactor": http://www.te.com/usa-en/products/relays-contactors-switches/contactors/mil-aero-contactors/dc-contactors.html?tab=pgp-story

(Obviously those are the expensive ones, but you should be able to find a e.g 50A contactor somewhere)

However, since this is apparently for an electric go-kart, you might want to think about speed control before going much further ...

Answer (score 0):

Solar disconnect switches are designed for high currents like this. Here is one that would appear to meet your stated requirements...

http://www.industrialcontroldirect.com/dc-disconnects-316/enclosed-dc-disconnects-317/dc-disconnect-4088.html

But I would echo @jbord39's comments - this is enough current to  weld contacts and vaporize conductors so you should probably try to find someone with experience to help out.

Comment: Be careful using disconnect switches for actual switching. Usually a disconnect is designed to _isolate_ an already dead circuit rather than _switch_ a live one. The contacts may be slow to break and cause arcing and wear if used for switching.